# Image Not Added to PDF using FPDF

Tags: pdf, fpdf

I'm using FDPF to create a PDF from a HTML form, and there is an uploaded image that I want to add to the top of the first page. Here's what I have for the line to add the image:

```
$pdf->Cell(40,40,$pdf->Image($uploadfile,10,10,-300), 1,'C',false);
```

But when the PDF is created, the image isn't there. I've tried all the other answers that I could find here, but nothing seems to be working. I know that the image is being uploaded, so I can't understand why it isn't showing up on the PDF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your call to Image() should not be inside your call to Cell(). Try just $pdf->Image($uploadfile,10,10,-300) on its own.

Comment: I've tried that before. It still doesn't put the image on the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The variable for the image URL wasn't being passed to the function. I added the upload part of the code handler to the function and added the image in the header, then added more lines after it so that the body text would be put after the end of the image.